# How to add Cross button with item adding in EditText

Tags: android, input

I'm trying to replicate feature provided by SMS application, add contact with option to cancel it. What this called and how can implement for Android application.

[image]

Comment: have a look at this  library https://github.com/splitwise/TokenAutoComplete

Comment: it is not exact what you want but it may helps you . you have to change it according to your need

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call it as TagView or ChipsView. Here i am sharing some library links, checkout those:

https://github.com/loopeer/MultiTextTagView
https://github.com/splitwise/TokenAutoComplete
https://github.com/kpbird/chips-edittext-library
https://github.com/klinker41/android-chips
https://github.com/whilu/AndroidTagView

As you want cross button in it, you need to modify its item layout and give click listener and than everything is depend on your logic.